# R - How to not change axis ranges when plotting two factor series

Tags: r, plot

[image: Graph]My code:

```
plot(factor(tData$Interval), tServiceLev, col = "red", type = "l", main = 

'Service Level and Call Volume', xlab = "Time Intervals", ylab = "Service Level")
lines(factor(tData$Interval), tServiceLev, type = "l", col = "blue",lwd = 2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(factor(tData$Interval), tData$Offered, type = "l", axes=FALSE, col = "green")
axis(4)
mtext("Call Volume", 4,1.5)
lines(factor(tData$Interval), tData$Offered, col = "red", lwd=2)
legend("topright", col=c("blue","red"), lty = 1, legend = c("Service Level", "Call Volume"), cex = .85)
```

When I put on the second plot, it overwrites the left axis completely. Also is there a way to make the actual graph larger and the axis labels closer to the axis range values?

Edit: This is my new graph after I knitted rmd. Call Volume is cut off. I want the time intervals to be as shown, but coloring each data point does not work. I guess part of the confusion is working with factored data which I've never worked with before.

Comment: Please provide some data to make it easy to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Plot option `yaxt = "n"` in your second `plot` call, see `?par`.

Comment: You should probably also make sure they are scaled equivalently. So a more appropriate plot call after the `par(new = TRUE)` is something like `plot(factor(tData$Interval), tServiceLev, type = "l",ylim = par()$usr[3:4],axes = FALSE)` - last plot option because you don't want it to make the x-axis twice.

Comment: @Jimbou tData$Interval are 30 minute intervals from 8 AM to 5 PM. tServiceLevel ranges from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `plot()` calls, you need to set `axes=FALSE`.  Then you can use `axis()` subsequently to customize the axes as you wish (using `side=1` for bottom, `side=2` for left axis).

For the other adjustments, try preceding `plot` with a call to `dev.new(width=8, height=8)`, for example, launching an 8" by 8" device. Then using `par(mai=c(2,2,1,1))` you can set 2" margins at bottom and left, 1" at top and right.  Adjust those numbers as needed to get the proper size.

When calling `axis`, use `axis(..., labels=FALSE)` to make the axis with ticks, etc.  Then print the actual labels using `mtext`.  The `lines=..` option within `mtext` will allow you to set the distance off the axis that the labels plot.

Update: Again, have you tried setting more space for the margin using `par(mai=c(bottom,left,top,right))` as I suggested above?  Using a larger number for `right` should give more space for the axis label. Also, try using `type='o'` to plot makers and lines.  Still not understanding the change you'd like to make to the x axis.

Comment: The axes don't show a time interval, e.g., 8 - 5 PM. Instead it just shows 0:10

Comment: So you want the x axis to be labeled with times, which are stored in tData$Interval?  What is the `type` on Interval, e.g. by calling `str(tData)`?  Please be more explicit regarding what you want the plot to look like.